# Custom Report Items in local reports

Tags: rdlc, report

i have read this article about custom report items(CRI)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188686.aspx
The only problem is that CRI are only usable in reporting service and not in local reports. My question is it possible some how to use CRI in local reports( RDLC ). Also i am interested in which version of reporting service is this possible, if possible
Best Regards,
Iordan

Answer (score 1):

Custom report items are not supported in .rdlc files. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251712(v=vs.90).aspx) This is likely the approach taken by Microsoft because the ReportViewer used with these files is a free control, while more complex features like third-party controls are supported only on a full SQL Server report server.

One thing in particular I have done in the past to get around this is generate custom charts/controls/images etc. As images and then send them into the report as an image.  Not an ideal solution but it works.